# Cancel Build if Task Runner Explorer Task Fails

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I am using visual studio task runner (2015) to run a Gulp task bound to before build.

I have set it up so that when the gulp tasks fails it sends exit code 1 and at the end it says "Process terminated with code 1." however the build continues.

This will cancel the build in team city so seems an issue linked Task Runner inside visual studio.

How can I prevent the build from taking place if it exits with a code other than 0?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are correct in that this seems to be a Task Runner issue.  The task runner does not communicate with MSBuild to stop a build if a BeforeBuild task fails.

To get around this, you can run your Gulp task via the project's pre-build event instead of via the Task Runner bindings.

**Set the pre-build event**

For class libraries, you can access Build Events by right-clicking your project and selecting `Properties -> Compile -> Build Events...`.

For web projects, they are located at `Properties -> Build Events`.

Here is the command I used to call the Gulp task in pre-build event, which will prevent the MSBuild from running if it exits with a failure:

`gulp -b $(ProjectDir) --gulpfile $(ProjectDir)gulpfile.js my-task`

This command calls Gulp passing absolute paths for working directory and `gulpfile.js`.

Notes:

- I found all kinds of context and working directory issues trying to use a more straight up command like `gulp my-task`.
- `$(ProjectDir)` is one of the [Macros for Build Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).
- It is assumed that Gulp is installed globally: `npm install -g gulp`.  See [jonas.ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688464/jonas-ninja)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064728/120783) for how to build this install into the command (or for an alternative that does not require the global dependency).

Answer (score 4):

I implemented davidmdem's solution above and it was great... on my system. I had `gulp` installed globally, but one of my coworkers did not, so the pre-build event would fail. Running gulp from Task Runner Explorer uses the **project-level** gulp installation, but running gulp from the pre-build script uses the **global** gulp installation.

To prevent the situation where a new developer doesn't have gulp installed, I expanded davidmdem's pre-build script to the following:

`(gulp --version || npm install -g gulp@3.9.0) & gulp -b $(ProjectDir) --gulpfile $(ProjectDir)gulpfile.js my-task`

This command installs gulp (version 3.9.0 to match the project-level gulp installation) *only* if it is not already installed. Now gulp is not something that you have to think about before you can build the project!

---

***(Update:)***

An alternative (in my opinion: better) solution to this problem is to use `npm` as an intermediary. Continuing and modifying from the example above, I have a gulp task `my-task` that is being called from the command line. This removed the global gulp dependency and still properly stops msbuild if gulp fails.

**Pre-build event:**

```
npm run build
```

**package.json:**

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "gulp min"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have build fail for jshint with gulp working (well enough for me, maybe sufficient for others.)  I imagine it may be extended to include all the tasks in Task Runner.

Here is what I used/did...

As per [this](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#scripts) page, I added/edited this in my **project**.json, which hooks into the prebuild event...

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": [ "gulp default" ]
  }
```

As per [this](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint#fail-reporter) page, I included the following for my jshint task...

```
// =============================
// jsHint - error detection
// =============================
gulp.task("jshint", function () {
    var jshGlobals = [
        '$',
        'jQuery',
        'window',
        'document',
        'Element',
        'Node',
        'console'
    ];

    gulp.src([paths.jsFiles, norefs])
        .pipe(jshint({
            predef: jshGlobals,
            undef: true,
            eqnull: true
        }))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
});
```

The latter two lines being the most significant. You will need to npm install `jshint-stylish` if you don't already have it.

Alternatively, for `jshint-stylish`, you can let VS handle it for you.  Add the line for `jshint-stylish` as indicated below to your **package**.json...

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "~3.1.2",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "jshint": "~2.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "~6.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "~6.3.3"
  }
}
```

Which gives me this when there is an error (in addition to the failed build) which is sufficient for me to dig further if/as necessary...
[image: vs error list window after build]

As opposed to the more detailed error info I get when running the same task via command line or Task Runner...
[image: gulp default task output via cmd.exe]

I imagine this solution can be improved but figured I would share as I hadn't seen a whole lot about it elsewhere.

Cheers.