# Fail msbuild when gulp task fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, gulp

I just started to learn `gulp` tasks for checking javascript files. I am using `ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Framework)` project type.

I am trying to fails `msbuild` when the `gulp` task fails. Here is the task:

```
gulp.task('jshint', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wwwroot/lib/test/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter("fail"));
});
```

Here is the only one javascript file with code:

```
LHG^(&^%(*&^%(*&)))
```

When I build the project(I binded to run task before build in the `Task Runner Explorer`), the task generates errors in the `Error List` tab. But I am getting:

> ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

in the `Output` window. i came across this question [Cancel Build if Task Runner Explorer Task Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759446/cancel-build-if-task-runner-explorer-task-fails) where it suggests to run the task from pre-build event, but the problem is this project type doesn't seem to have `build` tab in its `Properties` window. I suspect that it can be done via some json configuration file, but I can not find any related information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XPROJ files do not have traditional CSPROJ pre-build/post-build events. You can specify them in project.json. I would highly recommend migrating away from XPROJ back to CSPROJ, in line with what Microsoft are doing.